# handle multiple request accessing a json file

Tags: php, json, file, nginx

I have json file in text having a sample data

```
{"msisdn":"xxxxxxxxxx","productID":"YYYYYYYY","subdate":"2018-09-28 16:30:35","Status":"1"}
{"msisdn":"xxxxxxxxxx","productID":"YYYYYYYY","subdate":"2018-09-28 16:30:35","Status":"1"}
```

and I have a php code that check the json file for existing msisdn

```
class JSONObject implements JsonSerializable
{
    public function __construct($json = false)
    {
        if ($json)
            $this->set(json_decode($json, true));
    }
    public function set($data)
    {
        foreach ($data AS $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $sub = new JSONObject;
                $sub->set($value);
                $value = $sub;
            }
            $this->{$key} = $value;
        }
    }
    public function jsonSerialize()
    {
        return (object) get_object_vars($this);
    }
}

function checkmsisdnallreadyexists($file,$msisdn)
{
    if (is_file($file)) {
         if (($handle = fopen($file, 'r'))) {
            while (!feof($handle)) {
                $line          = trim(fgets($handle));
                 $jsonString    = json_encode(json_decode($line));
                // Here's the sweetness.
                //$class = new JSONObject($jsonString);
                $class         = new JSONObject($jsonString);
                if($class->msisdn == $msisdn)
                {
                    $date1=date_create($class->subdate);
                    $date2=date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
                    $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2);
                    if($diff->format('%a') < 31)
                    {
                        fclose($handle);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            fclose($handle);
         }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Everything is working fine initially but when my json file has more than 30 000 records, we have a read timeout. as we have a huge request on my server approx 200k request per hour resulting in efficiency of the whole process.

Can any one provide a solution or a alternate method?

Note: I can't use database here

Comment: You could try `file(...)` instead of `fopen() ... fclose()`. It only reads the file and you can process the data without blocking the file longer than necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `file()` instead of `fopen() and fclose()`

```
function checkmsisdnallreadyexists($msisdn){ 
  $file_array = file('give file path',FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES); 
  foreach($file_array as $arr){ 
      $msisdn_array = json_decode($arr,true); 
      $msisdn_value = $msisdn_array['msisdn']; 
      if($msisdn_value == $msisdn) { 
         $date1=date_create($msisdn_array['subdate']); 
         $date2=date_create(date('Y-m-d H:i:s')); 
         $diff=date_diff($date1,$date2); 
         if($diff->format('%a') < 31) { 
             return true; 
         } 
      } 
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help .  This code runs faster than mine (approx 6 times ) but it still fails due to the heavy traffic.